# Create Windows Symbolic Link with Java (equivalent to MKLINK)

Tags: java, windows, filesystems, symlink

Could anyone please tell me how to make a symbolic link (in the same way MKLINK does) and/or remove a symbolic link with Java. I have found solutions that use Java as a wrapper and use a Windows native program to accomplish this, but I really want a pure Java solution. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Java 7 you can do this easily using the NIO package.

```
Path target = Paths.get("target");
Path link = Paths.get("link");
Files.createDirectory(target);
Files.createSymbolicLink(link, target);
```

Do remember that you do need the correct privileges for this. In my unit test I had to run eclipse as an administrator to make it work (same as that I couldn't create a link from a normal `cmd.exe`)

Comment: Alternatively, you can enable [Developer Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development) (on Windows 10 version 1703 or newer) which will allow you to create symlinks without without running as admin.

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know window does not have *real* symbolic links like Unix-like system do.

However Windows has the following relevant tools:

1. You can map network drive, i.e. attach drive letter to specified network path. You can definitely do this using WMI. To access WMI from java take a look on tools like JaWin, Jinterop, Jintegra or write WMI script in JScript o VBScript and execute is from Java.
2. You can use command `subst` that assigns letter to local file system path. This is the closest approach to Unix soft link.
3. You can create desktop shortcut. Create one manually and take a look on it. Shortcut is actually regular text file (as far as I remember in INI format). You can easily create one using any language you want including java. This is not soft link but it is clickable.

Comment: Well Windows Vista/7 has some sort of symbolic links. The MKLINK command-line utility accomplishes this. Is there no way in Java to emulate what this utility does?